# Migrate AZ keyvault secrets using a filter

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

i have the following question.
I have a shell script that copies the values and secrets from 1 vault to another.
I have also found a Powershell script for this.

But my real question is can i make it so that it only transfers the values from a given list.
Such as a secretfilter?
If it is in powershell or bash makes no difference for me.
Thank you all in advance!

Below are the scripts i found for bash and powershell

```html
#!/bin/sh
#
# az account set --subscription "BCONN-DEV"
# az keyvault list -o table
# => westeurope  kv-aks-accept-001     rg-aks-accept-001
# => westeurope  kv-aks-dev-001        rg-aks-dev-001
#=> westeurope  kv-aks-prod-001       rg-aks-prod-001
SECRETS="enkrs-secret-0e enkrs-secret-0a enkrs-secret-0b"
SOURCE_KEYVAULT="enkrs-kv01"
DESTINATION_KEYVAULT="enkrs-kv02"
for SECRET in $SECRETS; do 
  az keyvault secret show --vault-name $SOURCE_KEYVAULT --name "$SECRET" --output json > "$SECRET".json
  NAME=$(jq --raw-output '.name' "$SECRET".json)
  VALUE=$(jq --raw-output '.value' "$SECRET".json)
  EXPIRES=$(jq --raw-output '.attributes.expires' "$SECRET".json)
  DESCRIPTION=$(jq --raw-output '.contentType' "$SECRET".json)
  rm "$SECRET".json
if [ "$EXPIRES" = "null" ]; then
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $DESTINATION_KEYVAULT --name "$NAME" --value "$VALUE" --description "$DESCRIPTION"
else
    EXPIRES=$(echo "$EXPIRES" | cut -c-10)
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $DESTINATION_KEYVAULT --name "$NAME" --value "$VALUE" --description "$DESCRIPTION" --expires "$EXPIRES"
    fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're providing a static list of secrets to parse, this can be done by using a variable, let's say:

```
SECRETS="secret1 secret2 secret3"
```

then you need to change this line:

```
for SECRET in $(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $SOURCE_KEYVAULT --output json | jq --raw-output '.[].name'); do
```

into this:

```
for SECRET in $SECRETS; do
```

Also, you're assigning values to some variables on the top of your script...

```
#
​azsub="test-DEV"
src_kv="test-kv01"
dest_kv="test-kv02"
```

and you're re-assigning those variables to other variables

```
SOURCE_KEYVAULT=$src_kv
DESTINATION_KEYVAULT=$dest_kv
```

this is redundant and useless, just pick one name and use it in your script. Also, you're declaring the variable `azsub` which is not used anywhere, so assuming there isn't any more code into the script you can just remove it.

Comment: First of all thank you for you feedback i have edited the code as mentioned above.
Im now getting the following error : 

------
shell_migrate.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'shell_migrate.sh: line 11: `for SECRET in $SECRETS; do'
---------

Comment: I have updated the snippet above again thank you in advance!

Comment: Check for any typo in your script mate :) look at your `do`.

Comment: Also, try using https://www.shellcheck.net/ this tool should highlight you all typos and invisible chars like that carriage return after `do` that bash is complaining about

Comment: Thank you for the tips the shellcheck helps, it is still throwing errors even though the shellcheck says everything is OK weird but still.
Maybe you can see it in a flash where i have been slamming my head against a wall for a few hours now.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I don't have the vault software installed on my pc so i won't be able to reproduce.

Comment: Shell scripts are sensitive to line ends, I would recommend checking the EOL characters to be in a UNIX format: `\n`. You might have a Windows style `\r\n` after `do`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a list of secret names and loop through.
Here is a sample using PowerShell and Azure CLI:

```
# az login
# az account set --subscription "<subscription-id>"

$sourceKvName = "thomastestkv1"
$targetKvName = "thomastestkv2"

$secretNames = @(
  "secret1",
  "secret2"
)

foreach ($secretName in $secretNames) {
  $existingSecret = az keyvault secret show `
    --vault-name $sourceKvName `
    --name $secretName `
  | ConvertFrom-Json
  
  # Create the secret
  az keyvault secret set `
    --vault-name $targetKvName `
    --name $secretName `
    --value $existingSecret.value `
  | Out-Null

  # Set content type if defined
  if ($existingSecret.contentType) {
    az keyvault secret set-attributes `
      --vault-name $targetKvName `
      --name $secretName `
      --content-type $existingSecret.contentType `
    | Out-Null
  }

  # Set activation date if defined
  if ($existingSecret.attributes.notBefore) {
    az keyvault secret set-attributes `
      --vault-name $targetKvName `
      --name $secretName `
      --not-before ([DateTime]$existingSecret.attributes.notBefore).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") `
    | Out-Null
  }
  
  # Set expiration date if defined
  if ($existingSecret.attributes.expires) {
    az keyvault secret set-attributes `
      --vault-name $targetKvName `
      --name $secretName `
      --expires ([DateTime]$existingSecret.attributes.expires).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") `
    | Out-Null
  }

  # Set tags if defined
  if ($existingSecret.tags) {
    $tagArray = @()
    foreach ($prop in $existingSecret.tags.PsObject.Properties) {
      $tagArray += "$($prop.Name)=$($prop.Value)"
    }

    az keyvault secret set-attributes `
      --vault-name $targetKvName `
      --name $secretName `
      --tags $tagArray `
    | Out-Null
  }
}
```